# GPG truncating lines

Tags: windows, gnupg, openpgp

I'm attempting to send a signed file to a recipient. When they received the file, they noticed that some of the lines had been truncated to 80 characters. If I look at the original file, it looks correct, but when I try to verify it on my machine, it tells me that there isn't any openPGP data contained in the file.

I'm on Windows, and I have no idea what OS the recipient is using.

Here's a scrubbed version of one of the lines that got truncated. In the actual file, most of those zeros are other numbers.

```
00000000000         000000000000000000000000TOWN OF UL                         000000000
```

I'm using `gpg --batch --yes --passphrase foo -s -u bar file_name`

Comment: Please provide example input (which fails on your setup), and how signing and verification are performed (exact command line options).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect you're actually getting hard wrapping instead of truncation.

There should be a line-wrapping option in your GPG tool, which might do the trick... The general recommendation seems to be to set line wrapping to 70 chars as some email systems start wrapping around 72 chars.

Comment: That would make sense. I would set it to that, but these are ACH files, and each line has to be 94 characters.

Comment: The source data? That should be unaffected, what you want is GPG to wrap is its output... On decryption the original file will be restored untouched.

Comment: that's what I thought. That's why I'm thinking that GPG might be truncating on the sign and compress.